# How to register areas for routing

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I created MVC Application that have 3 different Area. (Admin, User, News)
This is my RouteConfig.cs File in App_Start directory:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new[] { "TestMvcApplication.Controllers" }
        );
    }
}
```

And This is my AdminAreaRegisteration.cs file:

```
    namespace TestMvcApplication.Areas.Admin
{
    public class AdminAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
    {
        public override string AreaName
        {
            get
            {
                return "Admin";
            }
        }

        public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
        {
            context.MapRoute(
                "Admin_default",
                "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                namespaces: new[] { "TestMvcApplication.Areas.Admin.Controllers" }                
            );
        }
    }
}
```

And finally this is my Global.asax.cs file content:

```
namespace TestMvcApplication
{
    // Note: For instructions on enabling IIS6 or IIS7 classic mode, 
    // visit http://go.microsoft.com/?LinkId=9394801

    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
            AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();
        }
    }
}
```

Home page of my website fully loaded and it's works. but Homepage of Admin or other areas are not detect by route and I gave this error message:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /Admin/Home
```

How can I solve this problem?
Thanks.

Comment: Do you actually have a home controller in your admin area?

Comment: Yes, I have a HomeController.cs class for each Area.

Comment: The routes look okay, but can you verify that you have a `HomeController.cs` with `Index` action and `Views\Home\Index.cshtml` view in the admin controller?

Comment: Does your HomeController have an Index method? Have you overridden the `AreaName` property?

Comment: Override code is in my class but I don't copy this property to my question.

Comment: @Mojitaba word of advice, always copy complete code otherwise people can only work on assumptions...See my answer for what is required for this to work.

Comment: Yes, All of this classes and views has been added to my project.

Comment: @James Sorry, it's my mistake. I Edited my question and put all of my code into it.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Call `AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas()` somewhere in your `RegisterRoutes`

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    ....
}
```

**Tip:** Use a tool like [RouteDebugger 2.0](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/04/12/routedebugger-2.aspx) or [Routing Debugger](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx) to investigate your routes

Get latest  NuGet: 
[Route Debugger for MVC](https://www.nuget.org/packages/routedebugger/) or [RouteDebugger for WepApi](http://www.nuget.org/packages/WebApiRouteDebugger/)

Here's a tutorial on [How to set up and use RouteDebugger with WebApi](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/04/04/debugging-asp-net-web-api-with-route-debugger.aspx)

Comment: This code is in my Global.asax.cs file and Visual Studio created these methods.

Comment: What about Routing Debugger? Could you post the result?

Comment: I used route debugger but the page could not be loaded and still the problem remains. route debugger only show the routes in loaded pages only.

Comment: @Mojtaba: Thats why my preference is [Scott's Routing Debugger](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx) ;-) this one works always, even if the requested page doesn't show up.

Comment: I added Routing Debugger from NuGet to my project but in this code `RouteDebug.RouteDebugger.RewriteRoutesForTesting(RouteTable.Routes);` RouteDebugger does not exist. What can I do ?

Comment: Is there a reference to RouteDebug in your project?

Comment: The NuGet Package contains a file called RouteDebugger.dll but if you download the [zip](http://code.haacked.com/mvc-1.0/RouteDebug-Binary.zip) it contains RouteDebug.dll. And RouteDebug.dll works fine.

Comment: I also had the same issue RouteDebugger.dll not found but u just comment the line `RouteDebug.RouteDebugger.RewriteRoutesForTesting(RouteTable.Routes);` and enable the routedebug in web config and just run it will work fine. It worked for me.

Comment: Why is this marked as the answer?? So you got the debugger to work... What did the debugger tell you? What was the initial problem? What fixed it?

Answer (score 23):

From the code provided I can see 2 potential issues:

1. You aren't calling [RegisterAllAreas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee402951%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)
2. You don't appear to be overriding the [AreaName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.arearegistration.areaname%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) property

Try changing your code to:

**Global.asax**

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
        namespaces: new[] { "TestMvcApplication.Controllers" }
    );
}
```

**Admin area**

```
public class AdminAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
{
    public override string AreaName
    {
        get
        {
            return "Admin";
        }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Admin_default",
            "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Just create a static class name it **AreaConfig** with a static method **RegisterAreas()** here code:

```
public static class AreaConfig
{
    public static void RegisterAreas()
    {
        // 
        // Admin area . . .

        var adminArea = new AdminAreaRegistration();
        var adminAreaContext = new AreaRegistrationContext(adminArea.AreaName, RouteTable.Routes);
        adminArea.RegisterArea(adminAreaContext);


        // 
        // Default area . . .

        var defaultArea = new DefaultAreaRegistration();
        var defaultAreaContext = new AreaRegistrationContext(defaultArea.AreaName, RouteTable.Routes);
        defaultArea.RegisterArea(defaultAreaContext);
    }
}
```

then call it in a Global.asax.cs file like this:

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        . . .

        AreaConfig.RegisterAreas();

        . . .
    }
```