# Not able to produce Absolute url with @Url.Action in MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I have MVC website where i am trying to make absolute URL with url.action but not succeed yet.

Here is code i am using:

```
 <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")">Home</a></li>
 <li><a href="@Url.Action("Contact","Home")">Contact</a></li>
```

Both Home and Contact are in same View.

So here is the error description: When I run the website it shows this url and open website perfectly. Now if I click on "Contact" link it shows correct URL:

```
 http://localhost:5423/Home/Contact
```

After that I am clicking on "Home" Link it gives me wrong URL:

```
http://localhost:5423/Home/Home/Index
```

Correct Url should be this:

```
http://localhost:5423/Home/Index
```

I don't know why its retaining "Home" in URL.

This is what I wrote in Global.asax.vb

```
Public Class MvcApplication
    Inherits System.Web.HttpApplication

    Sub Application_Start()
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas()

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration)
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters)
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes)
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles)
        AuthConfig.RegisterAuth()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Here is the code for  RouteConfig:

```
 Public Class RouteConfig
 Public Shared Sub RegisterRoutes(ByVal routes As RouteCollection)
 routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}")
 routes.MapRoute( _
 name:="Default", _
 url:="{controller}/{action}/{id}", _
 defaults:=New With {.controller = "Home", .action = "Index", .id =  UrlParameter.Optional} _
    )
 End Sub
 End Class
```

This is only the problem I am facing.

Please give your views and suggestions.

Comment: can you show your route config?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad  are you asking for webconfig or global?

Comment: The `RouteConfig.cs` file. If you don't have one of those, there should be a bunch of route config related code in the `Application_Start()` method found in `Global.asax.cs`.

Comment: yes it is in global file:                                                                                              
 Public Class MvcApplication
    Inherits System.Web.HttpApplication

    Sub Application_Start()
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas()

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration)
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters)
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes)
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles)
        AuthConfig.RegisterAuth()
    End Sub
End Class

Comment: Can you show all the calls to `.MapRoute()` method in your code? That will help us understand more about the routes are setup in your project.

Comment: @user1638889 Edit that into your question, not as a comment - it's unreadable in there.

Comment: @DavidG  i  edited my question.Please check now.

Comment: Can you show the code that's in `RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes)` please?

Comment: @JasonEvans  there is no method .MapRoute   in my code.

Comment: There will be in `RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes()`.

Comment: @JasonEvans  i am searching this method in my code.but there is no method.

Comment: There will be separate file in you App_Start>>Routeconfig.cs, please show it here

Comment: @JasonEvans   question is updates  please check now. Thanks

Comment: OK that looks fine. Can you do the same with `AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas()` please? What is the content of that method?

Comment: @JasonEvans  there are only 5 inside  App_Start  folder.                                      1)WebApiConfig,vb      2)FilterConfig.vb   3) RouteConfig.vb  4)BundleConfig  5)AuthConfig.vb         There is no AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas() inside App_Start folder.Please suggest.     thnaks

Comment: In the Global.asax.cs file you have this line `AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas()` so it must be getting the areas routes from there. If that code is not in App_Start, it must be somewhere else.

Comment: @JasonEvans i am trying to find RegisterAllAreas() by F12 and its going to Object Brower.

Comment: @JasonEvans  please suggest what to do now?

Comment: In your code, right-click on `RegisterAllAreas()` and choose `Go to Definition`. That will take you to the source code for that method. In there you will see calls to `MapRoute()` which should help us clarify what routes have been configured for your `user` area.

Comment: @JasonEvans   yes  its redirecting me Object.Browser..no code for this method.

Comment: That's weird. Is there no file in your project called `AreaRegistration.cs`, or a `.cs` file that contains the type `AreaRegistration`?

Comment: @JasonEvans  yes really no

Comment: what should you  suggest now?

Comment: Sorry I'm thinking of the wrong thing. You're right, that type is not going to be in your project.

Comment: The only thing I can suggest is to look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13454699/how-to-register-areas-for-routing) and copy the `AdminAreaRegistration` class, but call it `UserAreaRegistration` and change the other parts accordingly. That way you can create your own routes for the `user` area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, I think I was targeting the wrong thing. In your `RouteConfig.cs` file, ad new routes for `Home/Index` and `Home/Contact` (apologies for the C#, I don't use VB.NET anymore):

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "HomeLink",
        url: "Home/Index",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "ContactLink",
        url: "Home/Contact",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Contact" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

In your view, create the links like this:

```
<li><a href="@Url.RouteUrl("HomeLink")">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="@Url.RouteUrl("ContactLink")">Contact</a></li>
```

Doing this should fix your url issue. Why `Home` is appearing twice is unclear to me, but creating your own routes should help.

Comment: Jason thanks alot it really helps me  to fix issue.if you are available now then i want to ask you one simple thing?

Comment: Is this something you could ask in a new question? If you create a new question, and add another comment to here, I will see that in my notifications and I could have a look at what else you need to ask.

Comment: thanks.all issue related to route are resolves now.Now there is a minor issue.I am creating report in my same project.It works well with localhost beofre.Thist report page is normal .aspx page and its outside views. i am using this jquery to show report         $('#frameReport').attr('src',"Report.aspx?InvoiceID=" + $('#InvoiceID').val());
 $('#divframe').show();         it was working before  but now when i am clicking on "report"  button it need to redirect to this url  Report.aspx?InvoiceID='123'  but its retaining me on view  like this.http://192.168.1.100/InvoiceReport/Index.

Comment: I highly recommend that you create a new question for this, otherwise it is going to confuse other users seeing two different questions on the same page. Splitting up the questions will benefit other SO users.

Comment: Jason   i created a new question.Please check.Thnaks