# Web API 2 routing fails for literal segment

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-mvc-areas, asp.net-web-api-routing, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I'm facing an issue with Web API 2 routing for literal segments.

In one project, I have ASP.NET MVC and WebAPI2 running together, the project is also running MVC areas.

Under each area, there is API folder which contains APIs. I'm facing an issue when trying to request the following url:
**{host}/accesscontrol/api/reporting/bookings**.

- **accesscontrol** here is the area name
- **reporting** is the controller
- **bookings** is a literal segment.

The error I'm getting:
**No action was found on the controller 'Reporting' that matches the request.**

This is the controller that should receive this request:

```
[RoutePrefix("accesscontrol/api/reporting")]
public class ReportingController : ApiController
{
    [Route("bookings")]
    [ResponseType(typeof(Booking))]
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Bookings(string q = null)
    {
        //Code to get data
        return Ok(bookings);
    }
}
```

When I remove `[Route('Bookings')]` attribute, the request is working well regardless if **Bookings** segment is there or not.

This is the configuration of routing under area registration class:

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{
    context.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        "AccessControlApi_default",
        "accesscontrol/api/{controller}/{id}",
        new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

    context.MapRoute(
        "AccessControl_default",
        "accesscontrol/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

How can I let the app to understand those literal segments under areas?

## Edit

I'm calling `RegisterAllAreas` in **Global.asax.cs** file, as follow:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you try editing "[Route("bookings")]" to "[Route("bookings/{q?}")]" and see if that makes any difference?

Comment: @valentin I tried, same error result!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my issue by moving: `AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();` from **global.asax.cs** file to **RouteConfig.cs** file.

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces:  new[] {"WebPortal.Controllers"}
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work just add action after your controller in your MapHttpRoute and change [Route("bookings")] attribute to [ActionName("bookings")] and everything works.

```
  context.Routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

  context.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
      "AccessControlApi_default",
      "Accesscontrol/api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
      new { id = RouteParameter.Optional});
```

I hope this will help you out.

Comment: I read it, and it is exactly applied. I don't know where is the issue.

Comment: try adding this on your RegisterArea `context.Routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();` this will enable attribute routing.

Comment: I did, I added it before all other mapping code, but with same error result!

Comment: I tried to create my own project and it seems everything is working fine until I notice the you're creating your own registration class. I think this question is already answer in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13454699/how-to-register-areas-for-routing).

Comment: @AlBaraa Sh, I managed to make it work and I revised my answer. I hope it will help you.

Comment: I have other REST apis, so, there should be no action to let them work, right?

Comment: My problem is only in literal segments!

Comment: Those urls working fine: **accesscontrol/api/people/{id}/activate**, it is just a problem of mapping!!