# I added an area called home, moved my controller and view to it and now I can't connect to the index view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvcroutehandler

I already have controllers and views in folders under the project name. I added an Area folder and then an area inside it and called it Home and then moved my controller and index view into it. But when I connect to the index I get an error and it looks like the path where it's looking for the index is the old path, how do I change this to the new path?

Here is what I created

[image]

In 'HomeAreaRegistration' I see this under RegstrationArea

```
public class HomeAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration 
{
    public override string AreaName 
    {
        get 
        {
            return "Home";
        }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Home_default",
            "Home/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

But when I run the application in IE, here is what I see in the browser! It looks like it's looking for the index.cshtml in the old path location, not the new path location in the new area 'Home'

[image]

It looks like the route engine is looking in the wrong location. So here is what my RouteConfig.cs file looks like.

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Even when I try 'https://localhost:44301/Home/Index.cshtml' it throws a HTTP 404 error.

Comment: Add your custom location path, by declaring `ViewLocationFormats` in your view engine search. Or you can keep `HomeController` and use `RedirectToAction` on Index action method to your area.

Comment: can you show me an example of how you would modify the ViewLocationFormats? I'm not sure what that is?

Comment: PS: Can you also show code inside `HomeAreaRegistration.cs` file? I want to clarify the contents carefully before writing example code that includes `ViewLocationFormats` and route configuration steps.

Comment: I've reposted the code from HomeAreaRegistration

Comment: Your folder structure looking out of order. Please see my answer for correct structure and related changes for same.

Answer (score 3):

The 404 error shows the main problem itself: default routing and view engine search cannot found default `Index.cshtml` view file in `Views` directory on your project (i.e. `ProjectName/Views/Index.cshtml` pointed by route `~/Views/Home/Index`).

First, create a class to include view location search for your custom area like this example:

```
public class CustomView : RazorViewEngine
{
    public CustomView()
    {
        MasterLocationFormats: new[]
        {
            "~/Areas/Home/Views/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/Areas/Home/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml"
        }

        ViewLocationFormats: new[]
        {
            "~/Areas/Home/Views/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/Areas/Home/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml"
        }

        PartialViewLocationFormats = ViewLocationFormats;

        FileExtensions = new[]
        {
            "cshtml"
        };
    }
}
```

Then, include all areas and your custom view engine into `Global.asax`:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    // register all area locations
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    // clear default view engine
    ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();

    // add your custom view engine here
    // the custom view engine should loaded before default view engine (e.g. Razor)
    ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new CustomView());
    ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new RazorViewEngine());
}
```

If you have `RouteConfig` class on `App_Start` directory, make sure `RegisterAllAreas` has included before default route:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Additionally, add namespace of the controller name when required or the above solution still doesn't work:

```
public class HomeAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration 
{
    public override string AreaName 
    {
        get 
        {
            return "Home";
        }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Home_default",
            "Home/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new[] { "ProjectName.Areas.Home.Controllers" }
        );
    }
}
```

NB: Create `Home` directory under `Views` if you want to follow route convension `~/Areas/Views/Home/Index`, and put `Index.cshtml` file into it.

References:

[How to set a Default Route (To an Area) in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140208/how-to-set-a-default-route-to-an-area-in-mvc)

[How to register areas for routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13454699/how-to-register-areas-for-routing)

Answer (score 0):

you have to do below corrections in your solution:

1) Add a Folder Home in Views and place index.cshtml in it.
Folder structure for view must be: Home(Area name) > Views > Home (same name as controller) > index.cshtml (as shown in picture)

[image]

2)change namespace of your Homecontroller to (Solution name).Areas.Home.Controllers

3)Also you have to refer following route pattern for area:

```
localhost/AreaName/Controller/Action
```

which in your case:

```
https://localhost:44301/Home/Home/Index
```

Hope this might solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

your area folder structure look like this

[image]

Reister your area in Global.asax

```
AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
```

and try with this url

```
http://localhost:44301/Home/Home/Index
```