# This custom route does not work in MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, routes

I have these route definitions:

```
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "InboxToCompose",
                url: "Asistencia/Mensajeria/Componer/{origen}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Mensajeria", action = "Componer", area = "Asistencia" }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

Route "InboxToCompose" should map to this method:

```
    // GET: /Asistencia/Mensajeria/Componer/origen
    public ActionResult Componer(string origen)
    {

    }
```

This method is placed in "Mensajeria" controller in "Asistencia" area.

When I call this in view:

```
Url.Action("Componer", "Mensajeria", new { area = "Asistencia", origen = "Inbox" })
```

Generated URL is

```
/Asistencia/Mensajeria/Componer?origen=Inbox
```

That way, I can see that "origen" parameter is populated with value "Inbox" when the method is called.

However, I want it to be just

```
/Asistencia/Mensajeria/Componer/Inbox
```

If I use that URL in browser, the method is called, but with "origen" parameter equal to null.

Any advice on this, please?

Comment: If you have areas, you need to register then in your `RouteConfig` file. Refer [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13454699/how-to-register-areas-for-routing) for an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of tries and errors, I have found the solution.

The fact is that since this controller belongs to an area, the route should be defined in AreaRegistration derived class.

I have found that this class contains this:

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
{
    context.MapRoute(
        "Asistencia_default",
        "Asistencia/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

So I moved my custom MapRoute from RouteConfig to AsistenciaAreaRegistration class. That way it worked. Both the URL generation using Url.Action and the parameter is received correctly.

I realized of this, after reading this page: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/

That page told about attribute routing, so I tried to add an atribute to my action, but, when I called AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();, a run time exception was thrown, telling that the area is already defined in AsistenciaAreaRegistration class.

So I decided to move the MapRoute to there as a logical deduction.

I prefer to add routes this way instead of attribute routing since in this way, I have all routings together, so it is easier to maintain in the future.

Regards

Jaime

Answer (score 0):

Please try below in route config

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "InboxToCompose",
            url: "Asistencia/Mensajeria/Componer/{origen}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Mensajeria", action = "Componer", area = "Asistencia" , origen = ""}
        );
```

Comment: No success... parameter is passed with the "?".

Comment: I have tried with attribute routing, adding the attribute and calling routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes(); while registering routes. In thise case, a 404 is shown with both Asistencia/Mensajeria/Componer and Asistencia/Mensajeria/Componer/Inbox

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `Url.RouteUrl`? Instead of passing the action and controller, you pass the name of your custom route as defined in `RegisterRoutes`. Replace the `Url.Action` line with this,

```
Url.RouteUrl("InboxToCompose", new { area = "Asistencia", origen = "Inbox" })
```

Comment: @jstuardo Glad to hear! If you found the answer helpful, then don't forget to upvote it or market it as accepted. Good luck coding!

Comment: False alarm, sorry.. this method generates the correct URL but the parameter is not actually passed.

Comment: so you're getting `/Asistencia/Mensajeria/Componer/Inbox` but the action isn't receiving the `origen` parameter?

Comment: Right... but I have found the solution. I will post it shortly